# Undefined type 'Google_Service_Sheets' (PHP)

Tags: php, php7, google-sheets-api

Пытаюсь подключиться к API Google таблиц. И столкнулся с такой проблемой: компилятор не видит мой класс Google_Service_Sheets.

[image: Скрин кода]

Вроде composer'ом всё установил(require google/apiclient:^2.0), должно работать... Но не видит.

Вот скрин вывода после запуска php sheet.php в консоли
[image: скрин ошибки]

Уже потратил несколько часов, чтобы понять, где ошибка.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит как будто vscode просто непроиндексировал класс, а фатальная ошибка происходит из-за другого.

Решение вашей ошибки можно посмотреть тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал, как там по инструкции и получилось.